# git: See changes to a specific file by a commit

Tags: git

I want to see the what changes were made to [this](https://github.com/LibreOffice/core/blob/master/include/svl/itemset.hxx) file's at line 147. So i enquired the file line by line for commits by:

```
git blame include/svl/itemset.hxx
```

Here is the trimmed output of git blame:

```
4b3a535ae3 include/svl/itemset.hxx         (Michael Stahl      2015-04-08 15:02:47 +0200 145)     SfxItemPool*                GetPool() const { return m_pPool; }
4b3a535ae3 include/svl/itemset.hxx         (Michael Stahl      2015-04-08 15:02:47 +0200 146)     const sal_uInt16*           GetRanges() const { return m_pWhichRanges;
 }
d210c6ccc3 svl/inc/svl/itemset.hxx         (Xiaofei Zhang      2010-07-29 10:56:19 +0800 147)     void                        SetRanges( const sal_uInt16 *pRanges );
d210c6ccc3 svl/inc/svl/itemset.hxx         (Xiaofei Zhang      2010-07-29 10:56:19 +0800 148)     void                        MergeRange( sal_uInt16 nFrom, sal_uInt16 nTo );
4b3a535ae3 include/svl/itemset.hxx         (Michael Stahl      2015-04-08 15:02:47 +0200 149)     const SfxItemSet*           GetParent() const { return m_pParent; }
```

Now i want to to see what changes did that commit with SHA `d210c6ccc3` to those lines. Basically i want to see the changes made by this commit to the file. So i did :

```
git show d210c6ccc3 include/svl/itemset.hxx
```

But this does not seem to give me right output, in fact it outputs nothing. Could anyone please suggest what could i be missing? Or maybe there is some other better way to know what changes were made to a file by a selected commit?

Comment: Commit `d210c6ccc3 ` modifies `svl/inc/svl/itemset.hxx` while file `include/svl/itemset.hxx` is modified by `4b3a535ae3`.... but your commit+file combination is not in the blame log. Maybe there is a rename or a symlink or something in the middle?

Comment: if that commit doesn't modify the file, then why is it in the output of git-blame? As far as i've read git blame gives lines and commits which modified those lines.

Comment: My guess is that the `include/svl` directory has been renamed into `svl/inc/svl` (or the other way around. Just use the alternate name to see your diff.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44245324/1256452) is correct (and I've upvoted it).  Here's *why*, though—along with the one other thing that can go wrong here.

In *most* cases, `git show commit -- path` would be correct and would show you:

- the log message for the specified commit, and
- a patch for that particular file, as produced by comparing that commit with its parent.

The patch would be the same as that produced by `git diff commit^1 commit -- path`.  (Note that the `^1` suffix here is literal text while the *`commit`* part is a hash ID that you replace.  The suffix syntax means "find the first parent".  You can add this suffix to most commit selectors, although not to selectors that use certain search patterns.  See [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).)

There are two important exceptions.  Only one of these applies here, because `git blame` normally does not blame a merge, it tries to trace the *source* of the change that fed *into* the merge.  Still, I want to mention it, because `git show`'s behavior on merges is ... interesting. :-)

If you look at a merge commit with `git show`, you will see, by default, a *combined diff* ("all parents" vs the merge commit's content).  In this case you may wish to fall back directly on `git diff`, so that you can specify the parent you want to compare (`^1`, `^2`, and even more if this is an octopus merge).  The reason is that combined diffs deliberately omit any file that matches the version in one of the parent commits: this means that whatever is in the repository from that point forward, it came from *one* of the two (or N if N > 2) "sides" of the merge.

With `git blame`, you are looking for "who changed what".  The person who did the merge is often not the person who made the change—so you should keep going "behind the merge" to find who *really* changed it.

The second exception is the one that caused a problem for you here, and it's really more a case of the way `git blame` works when files get *renamed* during development.

When `git blame` is analyzing changes to a file, such as `include/svl/itemset.hxx`, it steps back one commit at at time, starting from whichever commit you specify.  If you don't select your own starting point, it starts from from `HEAD`, i.e., the current commit.  It then looks at the parent commit(s) (as if via `git show` for instance).  For instance, if the current commit `922e935c8812` is an ordinary commit and its parent is `22c6554c98e2`, it compares commit `922e935c8812` to `22c6554c98e2`.  If `22c6554c98e2` has a file of the *same name*, that's probably the *same file* ... but if *not*, Git tries to figure out *which file* in `22c6554c98e2` is the same file as `include/svl/itemset.hxx`.

In this case, that exact thing happens at commit `b9337e22ce1d`.  There is a file named `include/svl/itemset.hxx` in commit `b9337e22ce1d`, but in commit `b9337e22ce1d^` or `f4e1642a1761`, the file is named `svl/inc/svl/itemset.hxx`.  Git detects this rename when stepping back from commit `b9337e22ce1d` to commit `f4e1642a1761`, and `git blame` then carries the *new* name back with it from commit `f4e1642a1761` to commit `d210c6ccc3`.

When you run `git show d210c6ccc3`, however, Git jumps directly to `d210c6ccc3` (and its parent `7f0993d43019`).  It no longer knows that the file named `include/svl/itemset.hxx` in `HEAD` is named `svl/inc/svl/itemset.hxx` in `d210c6ccc3`.  So *you* must discover this, and pass the earlier name to Git.

You might wonder how you can find this.  The answer is to use `git log --follow`.  The `--follow` code for `git log` is not great,<sup>1</sup> but it's the *same* code that `git blame` uses, so it produces the same answers, at least.  Here is what I did:

```
$ git log --oneline --follow --name-status include/svl/itemset.hxx
00aa9f622c29 Revert "used std::map in SfxItemSet"
M       include/svl/itemset.hxx
afaa10da2572 make SfxItemSet with SAL_WARN_UNUSED
M       include/svl/itemset.hxx
[snip]
a7724966ab4f Bin comments that claim to say why some header is included
M       include/svl/itemset.hxx
b9337e22ce1d execute move of global headers
R100    svl/inc/svl/itemset.hxx include/svl/itemset.hxx
```

There's a second rename even earlier.  Here's another, shorter way to find *only* the renames:

```
$ git log --oneline --follow --diff-filter=R --name-status include/svl/itemset.hxx
b9337e22ce1d execute move of global headers
R100    svl/inc/svl/itemset.hxx include/svl/itemset.hxx
e6b4345c7f40 #i103496#: split svtools in two libs, depending on whether the code needs vcl or not
R100    svtools/inc/svtools/itemset.hxx svl/inc/svl/itemset.hxx
```

If `d210c6ccc3` came "before" `e6b4345c7f40`, you would have to use the even-earlier path name—but commit `d210c6ccc3` is a descendant of (comes after) `e6b4345c7f40`, not an ancestor.

---

<sup>1</sup>When changes occur at merges, this really, in a fundamental sense, requires following *both* (or all) input commits simultaneously.  However, Git is not (currently?) capable of doing this: both `git log --follow` and `git blame` really only traverse whichever parent the final version of the file "came from".  That is, if we look at a typical merge commit `M` containing merged file `F`, there are two inputs `M^1:F` and `M^2:F`, and one output, `M:F`.  If `M:F` is the same as `M^1:F`, we should *ignore* `M^2:F` entirely: all the contents of `M:F` are those from whoever provided `M^1:F`.  If `M:F` is the same as `M^2:F`, we should *ignore* `M^1:F` entirely: all the contents of `M:F` are those from whoever provided `M^2:F`.

Note that this only works for *one file at a time*, and even then, it only works if the file *exactly matches* one of the two inputs.  Otherwise, we should look at the *combined diff* to see how the file got modified from *both* inputs.  This is the logic behind both combined diffs and History Simplification.  But it's over-simplified in some rare cases, and hence sometimes gets things wrong.

Comment: Strangely, on macOS I have git installed from macports with version 2.35.1, `git show commit -- path` shows nothing. But `git diff commit^1 commit -- path` returns correct diff.

Comment: @kkpattern: Is the given commit a merge commit? What happens when you run `git show -m commit -- path`? (See the paragraph in the answer that begins with `If you look at a merge commit`.)

Comment: with "-m" still outputs nothing. The exact same command works fine on my Windows git client.

Comment: @kkpattern: What's the output from `git rev-parse <commit>^@`? What about on the Windows system?

Comment: Both return two commit hash. The Windows git client returns one more empty line, but I don't think that makes any difference. The `git show commit` command works fine on macOS. But appending `-- path` doesn't work.

Comment: @kkpattern: OK, so it *is* a merge commit. It's odd that adding `-- path` should break anything, especially if the default combined diff shows that file. Are the combined diffs shown (when any are shown) otherwise the same?

Comment: I found that it may be because there is no content change of the file. It's a file mode change. Windows git client can still correctly output the mode diff. But git client on my mac failed to do so. For commits with content changes, the `-- path` actually works.

Comment: Aha. Still, `-- path` shouldn't suppress the mode-change note. This indicates a bug (small, but still a bug) in Git.

Answer (score 26):

You have to provide the path in that revision:

```
git show d210c6ccc3 -- svl/inc/svl/itemset.hxx
```

That should do

Comment: This will only show the commit message, author and date not the change in the file

Comment: @PeterReid: no, Edmundo is correct (try cloning the repository, though it's a bit large). You would generally be right if `d210c6ccc3` were a merge commit, but it's not.

Comment: If it were a merge commit and the content would come from one of the parents, you would still see _not_ the merge revision but the real revision where the lines were added.... _or_ if the lines were added on the merge (say, to correct a conflict or to correct some code that was not _complete_ after the merge.... this happens on some situations) the merge revision would show up on the blame output and then you would see some output for the file on the merge revision when using show.

Comment: @Edmundo: right, I was a bit overly terse here. One might come across a merge *not* via `git blame` and want to `git show` one file out of that commit, but if it's not part of the combined diff, `git show` doesn't show the file. If one comes across the merge via `git blame`, the change will be part of the combined diff so that `git show` *will* show the file after all.

Comment: right... but I guess you can select it as _"the"_ answer, right? That will suffice :-D

Comment: This will return no output if the file is deleted as opposed to the removed lines.

Comment: It does provide you with output if the file is deleted _if you use double dash_ (just checked.... on git 2.434.1)..

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
git diff d210c6ccc3^ d210c6ccc3 include/svl/itemset.hxx
```

to view the changes made to a file in commit (`d210c6ccc3`) compared to it's predecessor (`d210c6ccc3^`).

Where `d210c6ccc3^` is the 'base' and `d210c6ccc3` is the commit you want to compare to the base.

If as mentioned in comments on your question, you are looking at the wrong commit then replace the SHA above.

This will give a `diff` output of the contents of the files, the `git show` command you gave will output the commit message - only if that file was modified in the commit specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git diff <commit> -- include/svl/itemset.hxx`

Comment: Can you please add some explanation to your answer?